# Update variable value for each iteration inside a promise

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I want to update the value of `index`. In this scenario there is job card with multiple services in it and every service have multiple employees in it. So I want to create a multidimensional object with services an array inside job card object and employees an array inside each service but my index variable is not updating.

Here is the code

```
await Promise.all(
  services.map(async (service) => {
    const labor = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query(getLabor, [service?.labors_id], (err, result) => {
        resolve(result);
      });
    });
    rest.services.push(labor[0]);
    laborEmployee = service?.employees_id?.split(",");

    let index = -1;
    index = index + 1;
    rest.services[index].employees = [];
    console.log(index);

    await Promise.all(
      laborEmployee.map(async (emp) => {
        const e = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
          connection.query(getEmployee, [emp], (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            rest.services[index]?.employees?.push(result[0]);
            resolve(result);
          });
        });
      })
    );
  })
);
```

But my index variable remains the same. Currently there are two iterations so index should be 0 and 1 but it remains 0 and 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure just looking at the code, but my hunch would be to try defining the index variable outside of the scope of the initial `await Promise.all` as the way you have it currently, a new index is being defined for each Promise.